# Question about pruning and health of Orange tree

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, pruning

I am in south Louisiana, and we recently have had a much colder than average winter.  I have an orange tree in my backyard and I was planning on pruning it in the spring, and I am wondering about the overall health of the tree as well as where/how to prune it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would wait, before to prune (not to prune dead buds).